# make scrollable list in circular shape using libgdx

Tags: android, libgdx

I am developing a game using libgdx. I am stuck at making a list in the shape of a half circular which is also scrollable. This is a sample image (not circular)
[image]

which I want to be in similar shape like this.[image]

I know this question doesnt contain any code, but still I hope that someone will help me to solve this.

(I found that to make scrollble widget scrollpane can be used, but i have no idea how to make it as in the above shapes. )

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem with animation in android base lists. So, in every project we need custom behavior when scrolling. We developed [LinkedListView](https://github.com/GensaGames/LinkedListView) which provides some helper class - AnimationController, for creating custom scroll effect.

In your case, you should create your custom views transform, for creating circle. For ex. look at base IOS alarm. This is simple list, but every views transform their angle, and transparent, which create feeling of using drum.

[image: IOS Base Alarm]

Comment: Let me know, is it helps?

Comment: I am developing a game using libgdx, not in native. So wasn't much helpful. Nice lib tho...!

Comment: Only using "your custom views transform" - it's your answer... Anyway you using view in your libgdx, this library using view too. You may use lib as example for your own realization that list.

Comment: @GensaGames This is not the expected answer! You can put a comment rather than answer

Comment: @Stallion Based on answer: " know this question doesnt contain any code"! Anyway that library use algorithms to update view and create custom animated list, not just for android!